# How to do encode_entities on TMPL_VAR?

Tags: perl

I'm using `HTML::Template::Pro` and I don't find any information how I can do `encode_entities` on `TMPL_VAR` to cope with js injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TMPL_VAR NAME="foo" ESCAPE=HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about HTML::Template::Pro, but you can use escape attributes in HTML::Template like so:

```
<tmpl_var foo escape=html>
<tmpl_var bar escape=js>
```